# rails navigation active class for lower urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using rails 4. and i'm trying to achieve links to be active as long as "main" url checked.

All i want to do is:

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(events_path) %>"><%= link_to "Events", events_path %></li>
<li class="<%= 'active' if current_page?(contact_path) %>"><%= link_to "Contact us", contact_path %></li>
```

"Events" or "Contact us" links will be active as long as they are matching:

```
mydomain.com/events
mydomain.com/events/event-1
mydomain.com/events/event-1/job and etc.
```

How can i achieve that?

By the way I'm passing :id of events and i can't check if it's the current page, because sometimes i'm not passing the param.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use params[:controller] and params[:action] to check where you are.

It goes something like this :

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if params[:controller]=="events" and params[:action] == "index" %>"><%= link_to "Events", events_path %></li>
```

Of course you may need to tweak it to your precise needs.